# Access Form Fields in JNLP Launched Applictation

Tags: java, java-web-start

All,

I have been looking for this answer for several hours and I cannot seem to find a lot of great information.

I have been provided a URL to a JNLP file, which is opened via JavaWeb start.

When this application open, it has two fields.  One for a username and one for a password.  I can manually enter data into these fields and the application redirects me to where it should go.

My question is, is there any way to programatically access these fields for automation purposes?

There seems to be limited information on the subject.

Any assistance or pointers in the right direction are welcome.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Surely the java code of the started java webstart application can "programmatically access" the fields, but I suspect you mean something else? For automation purposes, the solution might depend on your OS, there are test suites that allow testing such stuff so there probably is some way, you might edit your question in that direction

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to automate the input of the username and password; you might be able to use a UI automation kit that can talk to the java UI appropriately e.g. [AssertJ-Swing](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing.html). however this generally requires those automation tools on the end system; which is probably not desirable. The `.jnlp` file *might* take username and password parameters, which could allow automating that way (again depends on the UI). Another approach would be decompiling the java app and altering it's behaviour.